# Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining: permission denied

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric

I created a small HyperLedger Fabric Network where I have a single channel with a single organization and a few peers along with an ordering service.

After going through the normal steps of creating my cryptographic materials , genesis block and channel.tx file I tried to create my channel in a cli container using the command:

```
peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c mychannel -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
```

After this, I received the following error:

```
Error: got unexpected status: FORBIDDEN -- Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining: permission denied
```

A part of the output of the cli container logs file:

```
2019-02-15 20:14:57.323 UTC [orderer/common/server] Start -> INFO 0ab Beginning to serve requests
2019-02-15 20:15:00.063 UTC [orderer/common/server] Deliver -> DEBU 0ac Starting new Deliver handler
2019-02-15 20:15:00.064 UTC [common/deliver] Handle -> DEBU 0ad Starting new deliver loop for 192.168.176.6:38938
2019-02-15 20:15:00.064 UTC [common/deliver] Handle -> DEBU 0ae Attempting to read seek info message from 192.168.176.6:38938
2019-02-15 20:15:00.068 UTC [orderer/common/server] Broadcast -> DEBU 0af Starting new Broadcast handler
2019-02-15 20:15:00.068 UTC [orderer/common/broadcast] Handle -> DEBU 0b0 Starting new broadcast loop for 192.168.176.6:38940
2019-02-15 20:15:00.068 UTC [orderer/common/broadcast] Handle -> DEBU 0b1 [channel: mychannel] Broadcast is processing config update message from 192.168.176.6:38940
2019-02-15 20:15:00.068 UTC [orderer/common/msgprocessor] ProcessConfigUpdateMsg -> DEBU 0b2 Processing config update tx with system channel message processor for channel ID mychannel
2019-02-15 20:15:00.068 UTC [orderer/common/msgprocessor] ProcessConfigUpdateMsg -> DEBU 0b3 Processing config update message for channel mychannel
2019-02-15 20:15:00.069 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 0b4 == Evaluating *policies.implicitMetaPolicy Policy /Channel/Writers ==
2019-02-15 20:15:00.069 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 0b5 This is an implicit meta policy, it will trigger other policy evaluations, whose failures may be benign
2019-02-15 20:15:00.069 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 0b6 == Evaluating *policies.implicitMetaPolicy Policy /Channel/Orderer/Writers ==
2019-02-15 20:15:00.069 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 0b7 This is an implicit meta policy, it will trigger other policy evaluations, whose failures may be benign
2019-02-15 20:15:00.069 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 0b8 == Evaluating *cauthdsl.policy Policy /Channel/Orderer/OrdererOrg/Writers ==
2019-02-15 20:15:00.069 UTC [msp] DeserializeIdentity -> DEBU 0b9 Obtaining identity
2019-02-15 20:15:00.069 UTC [msp/identity] newIdentity -> DEBU 0ba Creating identity instance for cert -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIICEzCCAbmgAwIBAgIQSNAnza0BnDG0ZBvOSPenpDAKBggqhkjOPQQDAjBvMQsw


(LONG TEXTS)9XYOAcEPDg==
    -----END CERTIFICATE-----
    2019-02-15 20:15:00.069 UTC [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU 0bb 0xc42016e118 gate 1550261700069869014 evaluation starts
    2019-02-15 20:15:00.069 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 0bc 0xc42016e118 signed by 0 principal evaluation starts (used [false])
    2019-02-15 20:15:00.069 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 0bd 0xc42016e118 processing identity 0 with bytes of 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
    2019-02-15 20:15:00.070 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 0be 0xc42016e118 identity 0 does not satisfy principal: the identity is a member of a different MSP (expected OrdererMSP, got dlMSP)
    2019-02-15 20:15:00.070 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 0bf 0xc42016e118 principal evaluation fails
    2019-02-15 20:15:00.070 UTC [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU 0c0 0xc42016e118 gate 1550261700069869014 evaluation fails
    2019-02-15 20:15:00.070 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 0c1 Signature set did not satisfy policy /Channel/Orderer/OrdererOrg/Writers
    2019-02-15 20:15:00.070 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 0c2 == Done Evaluating *cauthdsl.policy Policy /Channel/Orderer/OrdererOrg/Writers
    2019-02-15 20:15:00.070 UTC [policies] func1 -> DEBU 0c3 Evaluation Failed: Only 0 policies were satisfied, but needed 1 of [ OrdererOrg.Writers ]
    2019-02-15 20:15:00.070 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 0c4 Signature set did not satisfy policy /Channel/Orderer/Writers
    2019-02-15 20:15:00.070 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 0c5 == Done Evaluating *policies.implicitMetaPolicy Policy /Channel/Orderer/Writers
    2019-02-15 20:15:00.070 UTC [policies] func1 -> DEBU 0c6 Evaluation Failed: Only 0 policies were satisfied, but needed 1 of [ Orderer.Writers Consortiums.Writers ]
    2019-02-15 20:15:00.070 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 0c7 Signature set did not satisfy policy /Channel/Writers
    2019-02-15 20:15:00.070 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 0c8 == Done Evaluating *policies.implicitMetaPolicy Policy /Channel/Writers
    2019-02-15 20:15:00.070 UTC [orderer/common/broadcast] Handle -> WARN 0c9 [channel: mychannel] Rejecting broadcast of config message from 192.168.176.6:38940 because of error: Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining: permission denied
    2019-02-15 20:15:00.070 UTC [orderer/common/server] func1 -> DEBU 0ca Closing Broadcast stream
    2019-02-15 20:15:00.072 UTC [grpc] warningf -> DEBU 0cb transport: http2Server.HandleStreams failed to read frame: read tcp 192.168.176.4:7050->192.168.176.6:38940: read: connection reset by peer
    2019-02-15 20:15:00.072 UTC [grpc] infof -> DEBU 0cc transport: loopyWriter.run returning. connection error: desc = "transport is closing"
    2019-02-15 20:15:00.073 UTC [common/deliver] Handle -> WARN 0cd Error reading from 192.168.176.6:38938: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
    2019-02-15 20:15:00.073 UTC [orderer/common/server] func1 -> DEBU 0cf Closing Deliver stream
    2019-02-15 20:15:00.073 UTC [grpc] infof -> DEBU 0ce transport: loopyWriter.run returning. connection error: desc = "transport is closing"
```

The configtx.yaml file:

```
Organizations:
    - &OrdererOrg
        Name: OrdererOrg
        ID: OrdererMSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/msp
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.admin')"

    - &dl
        Name: dlMSP
        ID: dlMSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/dl.example.com/msp
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('dlMSP.admin', 'dlMSP.peer', 'dlMSP.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('dlMSP.admin', 'dlMSP.client')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('dlMSP.admin')"

Capabilities:
    Channel: &ChannelCapabilities
        V1_3: true

    Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
        V1_1: true

    Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
        V1_3: true
        V1_2: false
        V1_1: false

Application: &ApplicationDefaults
    Organizations:

    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"

Orderer: &OrdererDefaults
    OrdererType: solo
    Addresses:
        - orderer.example.com:7050
    BatchTimeout: 2s
    BatchSize:
        MaxMessageCount: 10
        AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB
        PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB
    Kafka:
        Brokers:
            - 127.0.0.1:9092
    Organizations:
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        BlockValidation:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"

Channel: &ChannelDefaults
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
    Capabilities:
        <<: *ChannelCapabilities

Profiles:
    SingleOrgOrdererGenesis:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *OrdererOrg
            Capabilities:
                <<: *OrdererCapabilities
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - *dl
    SingleOrgChannel:
        Consortium: SampleConsortium
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *dl
            Capabilities:
                <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
```

The crypto-config.yaml file:

```
OrdererOrgs:
  - Name: orderer
    Domain: example.com
    Specs:
      - Hostname: orderer

PeerOrgs:
  - Name: dl
    Domain: dl.example.com
    EnableNodeOUs: true
    Template:
      Count: 3                  #NUMBER OF PEERS
    Users:
      Count: 2                  #NUMBER OF USERS APART FROM THE ADMIN
```

The docker-compose-cli.yaml file

```
version: '2'

volumes:
  orderer.example.com:
  peer0.dl.example.com:
  peer1.dl.example.com:
  peer2.dl.example.com:

networks:
  v1:

services:

  orderer.example.com:
    extends:
      file:   base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: orderer.example.com
    container_name: orderer.example.com
    networks:
      - v1

  peer0.dl.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.dl.example.com
    extends:
      file:  base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: peer0.dl.example.com
    networks:
      - v1

  peer1.dl.example.com:
    container_name: peer1.dl.example.com
    extends:
      file:  base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: peer1.dl.example.com
    networks:
      - v1

  peer2.dl.example.com:
    container_name: peer2.dl.example.com
    extends:
      file:  base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: peer2.dl.example.com
    networks:
      - v1


  cli:
    container_name: cli
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools:$IMAGE_TAG
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      #- CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO
      - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.dl.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=dlMSP
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/dl.example.com/peers/peer0.dl.example.com/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/dl.example.com/peers/peer0.dl.example.com/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/dl.example.com/peers/peer0.dl.example.com/tls/ca.crt
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/dl.example.com/users/Admin@dl.example.com/msp
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: /bin/bash
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/chaincode
        - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
        - ./scripts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/scripts/
        - ./channel-artifacts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel-artifacts
    depends_on:
      - orderer.example.com
      - peer0.dl.example.com
      - peer1.dl.example.com
      - peer2.dl.example.com
    networks:
      - v1
```

The docker-compose-base.yaml file:

```
version: '2'

services:

  orderer.example.com:
    container_name: orderer.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:$IMAGE_TAG
    environment:
      #- ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=INFO
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=DEBUG 
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      # enabled TLS
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]

    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: orderer
    volumes:
    - ../channel-artifacts/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
    - ../crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
    - ../crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
    - orderer.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
    ports:
      - 7050:7050

  peer0.dl.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.dl.example.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.dl.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.dl.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer1.dl.example.com:7051
      # - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.dl.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=dlMSP
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/dl.example.com/peers/peer0.dl.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/dl.example.com/peers/peer0.dl.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
        - peer0.dl.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production
    ports:
      - 7051:7051
      - 7053:7053

  peer1.dl.example.com:
    container_name: peer1.dl.example.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.dl.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.dl.example.com:7051
      # - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer1.dl.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.dl.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=dlMSP
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/dl.example.com/peers/peer1.dl.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/dl.example.com/peers/peer1.dl.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
        - peer1.dl.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production
    ports:
      - 8051:7051
      - 8053:7053

  peer2.dl.example.com:
    container_name: peer2.dl.example.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer2.dl.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer2.dl.example.com:7051
      # - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.dl.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer1.dl.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=dlMSP
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/dl.example.com/peers/peer2.dl.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/dl.example.com/peers/peer2.dl.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
        - peer2.dl.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production
    ports:
      - 9051:7051
      - 9053:7053
```

Link to my code: https://mega.nz/#F!vJIUWKgZ!hx1geJ916PH0LrKKe5Q0RA!LQRBmITR

Comment: what is the value of the LOCALMSPID and the MSPCONFIGPATH environment variables you use for the peer channel create command?

Comment: @yacovm. As I have mentioned in my docker-compose-cli, CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=dlMSP
      
     . -----.  
    CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/dl.example.com/users/Admin@dl.example.com/msp

Comment: Maybe your certificates have expired so that the policies are not completed. Can you try by pruning once?

Comment: For running the network I have created a shell script in which I first delete the previous channel-artifacts and crypto-config files. Later, I delete the container, volumes and prune the network. So pruning shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Link to my code: https://mega.nz/#F!vJIUWKgZ!hx1geJ916PH0LrKKe5Q0RA!LQRBmITR

Comment: remove all containers and run - docker volume prune before starting the network

Comment: @Harshit. Already did that in my shell script. Please check it in the link provided if the sequence seems wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ./byfn.sh script  in genesis block creation you have written this command

```
echo "##########################################################"
echo "#########  Generating Orderer Genesis block ##############"
echo "##########################################################"

configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis -outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME
```

remove `-channelID $CHANNEL_NAME` from it and ignore this warning

```
2019-02-24 23:34:25.334 IST [common/tools/configtxgen] main -> WARN 001 Omitting the channel ID for configtxgen for output operations is deprecated.  Explicitly passing the channel ID will be required in the future, defaulting to 'testchainid'
```

It should work now. It did on my system.

Comment: This is bad practice, the ChannelID for genesis block is the one referring to system channel. Older versions use a default channel `testchainid` as system channel. In future versions, this will be removed and passing system channel name will be mandatory.

Comment: Thank you from 2020. However, I find it a bad naming convention to have one and the same command line argument name for system channel and for all other channels. I had problems, since I just used one and the same name for all calls of configtxgen. But yes, if I slowly read docs I get the difference.

Answer (score 10):

try using different names for ChannelID in command (here ChannelID value is **byfn-sys-channel** and it's so called "system channel"):

```
../bin/configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis -channelID byfn-sys-channel -outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block
```

and all the rest commands with ChannelID (here is DIFFERENT channel with ChannelID **mychannel**):

```
export CHANNEL_NAME=mychannel  && ../bin/configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputCreateChannelTx ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME
```

...

```
export CHANNEL_NAME=mychannel
peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked, but I'm still curious to why...

Answer (score 3):

I've got the same error.

```
Error: got unexpected status: FORBIDDEN -- implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Writers' sub-policies to be satisfied: permission denied
```

After removing everything in docker using this command, the error is sovled.

```
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)  ; docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq) ; docker system prune -a ; docker volume prune ; docker ps -a ; docker images -a ; docker volume ls
```

Especially the '**docker volume prune**' command is important.

Comment: Just a small addition, I also had to delete docker volumes related to the previous installation. Then it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
- &dl
    Name: dlMSP
    ID: dlMSP
    MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/dl.example.com/msp
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('dlMSP.admin', 'dlMSP.peer', 'dlMSP.client')"
        Writers:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('dlMSP.admin', 'dlMSP.client')"
        Admins:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('dlMSP.admin')"
```

It means it will allow only `'dlMSP.admin'` members to create channel

Make sure you have enough `attrs` in your certificate 
Below command make sure add admin attribute to the

```
fabric-ca-client register --id.name admin2 --id.affiliation org1.department1 --id.attrs 'hf.Revoker=true,admin=true:ecert'
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the channel has already been created and you're trying to send a proto file (channel.tx) with same channel identification.

If you're just trying to create a new channel, change the name of the channel and re-create the channel.tx and send the updated config in the cli command.

If you're trying to update the channel config, refer to [this](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/channel_update_tutorial.html) document and follow along to get latest config block and make necessary changes to the MSP ID as required.

Remember, Once the channel is created, the orderer only accepts the channel update config envelope to update the channel not the Channel Config file.

Comment: No I haven't created the channel yet. Thats what I want to do here. I have generated the crypto-config file with all the relevent certificates and keys. Also, the channel.tx file and genesis.block. I am certain that I haven't created the channel.

Comment: could you try to change the name of channel along with create new channel.tx file after editing the configx.yaml file and try again just to confirm?

Answer (score 1):

If you run into this problem just remove the old containers using

```
 docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -q)
```

Answer (score 0):

Either the channel is already created or you don't have permission to access it,for that you need to change the permissions.

The simpler solution is to remove all the containers and images and start again. The command is as follows:

```
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)                    //stop all containers first

docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)                     // remove all of them 

docker system prune -a                            // remove all stopcontainers

docker volume  prune                              //remove all volumes
```

Now again, start the network.